# vb script to parse file names and make csv

Tags: csv, vbscript

got a quick one for you guys hopefully...

I have a list of file names that are in this format:

ABCD_03105_221385_2015-02-20_03105.pdf
ABCD_03105_552589_2015-02-20_03105.pdf

I need to make a CSV of all these file names, with the fields separated by the underscores and the ".pdf" dropped off... so it would look like this in the file:

ABCD,03105,221385,2015-02-20,03105
ABCD,03105,552589,2015-02-20,03105

Help would be very much appreciated!!  Thanks

All I have so far is a script that will list the file names.  I'm not sure what to do to make them be split by the underscore.

```
On Error Resume Next
  Dim fso, folder, files, NewsFile,sFolder

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  sFolder = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
  If sFolder = "" Then
      Wscript.Echo "No Folder parameter was passed"
      Wscript.Quit
  End If
  Set NewFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sFolder&"\FileList.txt", True)
  Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
  Set files = folder.Files

  For each folderIdx In files
    NewFile.WriteLine(folderIdx.Name)
  Next
  NewFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace "_" with "," and ".pdf" with "". If you found errors, post here...

```
oldFile = "ABCD_03105_221385_2015-02-20_03105.pdf"
oldFile = lcase(oldFile)
newFile = replace(oldFile, "_", ",")
newFile = replace(newFile, ".pdf", "")
newFile = ucase(newFile)
```

Now, newFile must be "ABCD,03105,221385,2015-02-20,03105"

Comment: Thanks - I did get the underscores replaced with commas, but can't get pdf as well... i am trying this:    NewFile.WriteLine(Replace(folderIdx.Name,"_",","))(folderIdx.Name) -- if I add the same "Replace" next to the current working Replace, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Such as this:   NewFile.WriteLine(Replace(folderIdx.Name,"_",","))(Replace(folderIdx.Name,".pdf",""))(folderIdx.Name)    -- does not do the PDF portion, just the commas.

Comment: First, replace(oldFile, "_", ","). Second, replace(oldFile, ".pdf", "")

Answer (score 0):

You need to **nest** the Replace calls:

```
>> s = "ABCD_03105_221385_2015-02-20_03105.pdf"
>> t = Replace(Replace(s, "_", ","), ".pdf", "")
>> WScript.Echo s
>> WScript.Echo t
>>
ABCD_03105_221385_2015-02-20_03105.pdf
ABCD,03105,221385,2015-02-20,03105
```